# Parse XDocument without having to keep specifying the default namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xnamespace

I have some XML data (similar to the sample below) and I want to read the values in code.

Why am I forced to specify the default namespace to access each element? I would have expected the default namespace to be used for all elements.

Is there a more logical way to achieve my goal?

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReceiptsBatch xmlns="http://www.secretsonline.gov.uk/secrets">
    <MessageHeader>
        <MessageID>00000173</MessageID>
        <Timestamp>2009-10-28T16:50:01</Timestamp>
        <MessageCheck>BX4f+RmNCVCsT5g</MessageCheck>
    </MessageHeader>
    <Receipts>
        <Receipt>
            <Status>OK</Status>
        </Receipt>
    </Receipts>
</ReceiptsBatch>
```

Code to read xml elements I'm after:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load( FileInPath );

XNamespace ns = "http://www.secretsonline.gov.uk/secrets";

XElement MessageCheck = xDoc.Element(ns+ "MessageHeader").Element(ns+"MessageCheck");
XElement MessageBody = xDoc.Element("Receipts");
```

Comment: The logical way is to specify the namespace for each element. Just because you don't have to repeat the `xmlns` declaration in each element doesn't mean that child elements are in the default namespace (`xmlns=""`).

Comment: Is it possible to clear the default namespace to save me having to add "ns+" to each element name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory is that the meaning of the document is not affected by the user's choice of namespace prefixes. So long as the data is in the namespace http://www.secretsonline.gov.uk/secrets, it doesn't matter whether the author chooses to use the prefix "s", "secrets", "_x.cafe.babe", or the "null" prefix (that is, making it the default namespace). Your application shouldn't care: it's only the URI that matters. That's why your application has to specify the URI.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7387128/238753), you can do this by removing all namespaces from the in-memory copy of the document. I suppose this should only be done if you know you won't have name collisions in the resulting document.

```
/// <summary>
/// Makes parsing easier by removing the need to specify namespaces for every element.
/// </summary>
private static void RemoveNamespaces(XDocument document)
{
    var elements = document.Descendants();
    elements.Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        element.Name = element.Name.LocalName;

        var strippedAttributes =
            from originalAttribute in element.Attributes().ToArray()
            select (object)new XAttribute(originalAttribute.Name.LocalName, originalAttribute.Value);

        //Note that this also strips the attributes' line number information
        element.ReplaceAttributes(strippedAttributes.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [XmlTextReader.Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.namespaces(v=vs.110).aspx) property to disable namespaces while reading XML file.

```
string filePath;
XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(filePath);
xReader.Namespaces = false;
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xReader);
```

Comment: What it you have xml read already as string? XmlDocument has Parse only method for strings and you have to do a lot of work converting string to stream for xreader.

Answer (score 3):

This is how the Linq-To-Xml works. You can't find any element, if it is not in default namespace, and the same is true about its descendants. The fastest way to get rid from namespace is to remove link to the namespace from your initial XML.

Comment: Isn't the default namespace defined in the XDocument by defining xmlns="someNamespace". when you write the text version of the XML you don't have to specify the default ns so I wouldn't expect to have to do this with code.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the element `Receipts` is also in namespace `http://www.secretsonline.gov.uk/secrets`, so the `XNamespace` would also be required for the access to the element:

```
XElement MessageBody = xDoc.Element(ns + "Receipts");
```

As an alternative to using namespaces note that you can use "namespace agnostic" xpath using `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()`, e.g.

```
/*[local-name()='SomeElement' and namespace-uri()='somexmlns']
```

If you omit the `namespace-uri` predicate:

```
/*[local-name()='SomeElement']
```

Would match `ns1:SomeElement` and `ns2:SomeElement` etc. IMO I would always prefer `XNamespace` where possible, and the use-cases for namespace-agnostic xpath are quite limited, e.g. for parsing of specific elements in documents with unknown schemas (e.g. within a service bus), or best-effort parsing of documents where the namespace can change (e.g. future proofing, where the `xmlns` changes to match a new version of the document schema)