# Using C# to remove custom xml tags from html

Tags: c#, html, regex, xml, parsing

I have a string with some html code. However I need to parse that html to a `XDocument`.

```
string input = String.Concat("<root>", htmlString, "</root>");
var doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
```

But sometimes in my `htmlString` there is tags like `<o:p></o:p>`, for example, and with that in `XDocument.Parse()` I got the exception:

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a
>   name. Line 1, position 650.

How can I remove that tags or at least replace the `':'` in the tag name?

Before doing the parse I'm trying to remove/replace the `':'` but it isn't working:

```
try
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"<[:][^>]+>.+?</\[:]>");
    while (regex.IsMatch(htmlString))
    {
        htmlString= regex.Replace(htmlString, "");
    }
}
catch { }
```

**HTML example**

```
<p>Some text</p>

<p class="MsoNormal" style="TEXT-ALIGN: justify; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 150%">
    <?xml:namespace prefix="o" ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"?>
    <o:p> </o:p>
</p>

<p>More text</p>
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` but it doesn't remove this tags.

***My code***

```
ConfigureHtmlDocument();

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

var htmlError = htmlDoc.ParseErrors.SafeAny();

if (!htmlError)
    htmlString= htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

try
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"<[:][^>]+>.+?</\[:]>");
    while (regex.IsMatch(htmlString))
    {
        htmlString= regex.Replace(htmlString, "");
    }
}
catch { }

string input = String.Concat("<root>", htmlString, "</root>");
var doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

//more code
```

***ConfigureHtmlDocument()***

```
    if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("p"))
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("p", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
    else
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

    if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("ul"))
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("ul", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
    else
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["ul"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

    if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("li"))
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("li", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
    else
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["li"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

    if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("ol"))
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("ol", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
    else
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["ol"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

    //more similar code
```

Comment: Generally, parsing some HTML code using XML parser is not a good idea. HTML markup can contain other violations of "well-formed xml", not only tags like you've mentioned, and it still will be valid from HTML point of view, but completely invalid from XML one. If you need to parse HTML - consider using Html Agility Pack instead.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18503538/3832970). However, if the HTML is not valid XHTML, use HtmlAgilityPack or its alternatives.

Comment: I'm using HtmlAgilityPack but it doesn't solve the problem. I updated my question with that code

Comment: The letters before the colon are prefixes.  You must include a namespace definition for each prefix in the xml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The Regex expression is wrong. I replaced the expression with this:

```
//for remove xml declarations
htmlString = Regex.Replace(texto, @"<\?xml.*\?>", "");

//for remove custom tags like <o:p> and </o:p>
htmlString = Regex.Replace(texto, @"<(?:[\S]\:[\S])[^>]*>", "");
htmlString = Regex.Replace(texto, @"</(?:[\S]\:[\S])[^>]*>", "");
```

And now it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the namespace in advance the you can do something simple like this:

```
htmlString = htmlString.Replace("<o:", "<").Replace("</o:", "</");
```

Comment: I can't guarantee tag is always `<o:p>`. That was just an example